# what is the regular expression for "No multiple hyphens or double quotes permited!"

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can anyone told me how to write this regex for "No multiple hyphens or double quotes permited!"? 
I tried [^"--]*. But good-looking is not gonna passed.

Comment: Why can't you go ahead with `Contains()`? On a side note, you may find [this tool](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul is on the right track, but if you want a regex that evaluates to True for strings without quotes or double-hyphens, use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?:(?!"|--).)*$
```

Comment: I tried this, but it allows any number of -. For instance, good-looking will pass, that is fine. But good---looking will pass also, will is i don't want it to.

Comment: No, good---looking will not pass this regex. The existence of any two hyphens side-by-side will cause it to fail.

Comment: I put ValidationExpression='^(?!"|--).*$' for my regularExpressvalidator in my aspx, good--looking did pass it. It actually allow any number of hypens.

Comment: My bad, forgot that the lookahead would only be tested once that way. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

reading between the lines, it sounds to me like you might be trying to prevent a SQL injection attack by preventing the user from entering quote characters or SQL comments? If that's what you're trying to do, then this is not the way to do it.

What you actually need to do is make sure your string is properly escaped. If your SQL string is properly escaped then no amount of hyphens or quotes will cause you a problem, so there will be no need to block out hyphens or quotes, or any other dangerous characters.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want to test a string to ensure it does not have any `"` or `--` i would use this:

```
("|--)
```

If there is no match, the string is OK.

If this isn't what you want, please provide more info + examples.